# Can I 'git cherry-pick <sha>' and have 'git log foo..bar' recognize it?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

Background: I have two branches, master and stable, with many commits on master that aren't on stable.  I want to cherry-pick a number of those commits to stable, and then be able to use `git log --merges-only stable..master` to see what's left.

However, if I just cherry-pick, git treats them as two commits and thus the 'git log' command doesn't help.  E.g. given this:

```
# create a repo
mkdir cherry
cd cherry
git init

# add a commit on master
touch foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -a -m 'commit 1'

# create a stable branch
git checkout -b stable

# add two more commits to master
git checkout master
touch bar.txt
git add bar.txt
git commit -m 'commit 2'
touch baz.txt
git add baz.txt
git commit -m 'commit 3'

# cherry-pick just one of those commits to stable
git checkout stable
git cherry-pick master
```

Then, I'd like to be able to see what commits are candidates for future cherry-picking on master, ideally using `git log`, but it doesn't really answer my question:

```
> git log stable..master --pretty=oneline --no-merges
01550adab8993ceb1eec7bbc7a0e3de3550d63fc commit 3
8a3ea27aa50c887b603296bb9d4a36ccbfa35311 commit 2
```

However, TIL about `git cherry`:

```
>  git cherry stable master
+ 8a3ea27aa50c887b603296bb9d4a36ccbfa35311
- 01550adab8993ceb1eec7bbc7a0e3de3550d63fc
```

Where the entries prefixed with '+' are the candidates for future-cherry picking.

Comment: Git treats them that way because they *are* two different commits :-) ... `cherry-pick` diffs the "picked cherry" against its parent, and then applies that same change to `HEAD` as a new commit.  What you need (which git does provide) is to compare the *changes* made, pair-wise; see Magnus Bäck's answer.  Note that this is a fair bit of compute work (git has to compute the diffs, same as in the `cherry-pick` command, but now has to do this for every commit along the fork and then compare them all! it does quite fast for what it's doing, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git cherry` command is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebasing stable against master after you've cherry-picked all the commits you want:

```
git checkout stable
git rebase master
```

Comment: That will bring *all* the changes over from master to stable, which is just what I can't do.  I want to bring over a handful and then use 'git log' (or something) to show me what's left, omitting the commits I've already cherry-picked.

Comment: @Kylo You can make a trivial change to get `git checkout --detach stable` (checks out exactly the same code as `git checkout stable`, but leaves you with detached HEAD), then run exactly the `git rebase master` that's in this answer, and finally check `git log master..HEAD`. You may optionally want to do this on a temporary branch instead of using detached HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help you or not, but you may want to look at my [git-missing](https://github.com/jszakmeister/etc/blob/master/git-addons/git-missing) script.  It mimics Bazaar's `bzr missing` command.  It will show you the extra commits you have on your branch, followed by the commits that are missing from the other branch.  It takes cherry picks into account.

For example:

```
$ git missing master
You have 1 extra revisions
--------------------------
0db6b7c Call SetupSource for .zsh files.

You have 1 missing revisions
----------------------------
70f9f42 Add clojure snippets.
```